# How to make random.choice in a for loop give the same output every time

Tags: python, random, python-itertools, random-seed

I am reusing a code written by someone else. It has the following line included:

```
 df = (random.choice(x) for i in repeat(0))
```

However, because there is no random.seed, the output is different every time I rerun it, which makes sense.

I tried to fix this with `random.Random(500).choice(x)`, but since it's a for loop, it will then give me the same value for every iteration, which is not what I want.

Does anyone know how I make this pseudo-random?
Thanks!

Comment: What you want is not clear. Do you want n random values from a pool?

Comment: What is `x`? And might it get reassigned?

Comment: If you want the same random value from an iterable `x` repeated `n` times: `[random.choice(x)]*n`

Comment: @mozway How would you use that to achieve their goal?

Comment: Just assign the ``random.Random(500)`` outside of the loop and use it inside?

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `x` doesn't get reassigned:

```
df = map(random.Random(500).choice, repeat(x))
```

If it does:

```
df = (choice(x)
      for choice in [random.Random(500).choice]
      for _ in repeat(0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBBCoMwEEX3OcXsTIoUixRKoZfoVqSkmtSAZkISij29TYxiu3A2Yfj/v5mJ@fgOdXkxdprUYNB6sFy3OBBpcQDlhfWIvYNVFEZwn4NyvWoEISPcIJOIT24zQlrpQl8RCJXRBDo2HQYrHRlItKBA6YVCC8ayPJkHblb/fX7ouSjYks3XwLgF6D82dZFd7WLqnQVqQqLgohAuuM4DjFXaU8fmJsqPOcf1S9CSJU@sVoaLxZv3q3cLH9In0VbmcAqjfrhsmr4) (see the "Output" section)

Answer (score -1):

```py
import random

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

def repeat_random(choices):
    i = 0
    chosen = random.choice(choices)
    while i < 5:
        print(chosen)
        i += 1

repeat_random(nums)
```

# This will print a random number from the nums list 5 times